# Why does "raised" use past tense in this sentence "I was born and raised in Jakarta"

Tags: tense

I know `born` is once event so I can understand why `born` use past tense but how about `raised` ? it's still happening until now I'm growing in Jakarta, isn't it ? why we don't use present perfect continous tense as it started in the past and still happening until now ?

Comment: According to your profile, you're 24. Most native speakers would say you finished being "raised" many years ago. You *raise* children until they can reasonably be classed as [semi-]independent adults - which is somewhat subjective, but it ceases to be appropriate around age 15-18 for most people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Raised* here is not past tense but a past participle, parallel with born, and indicating a simple past passive:

> I was born in Jakarta.
>   I was raised in Jakarta.

We ordinarily use *raise* only for the period of your life when you are under the care of the parents or guardians who 'raise' you—that is, bring you successfully to adulthood. Consequently it is quite ordinary for adults to refer to their raising with a past-tensed verb construction.

Comment: hmmm I see, I think raised here is getting old. Thanks

Comment: @mockie, *to be raised* is to be brought to adulthood by one's parents.  *To get old* is to age, reaching old age.  You will have been raised by the time you leave your parents' care, probably somewhere between 16 and 25.  You will have gotten old by the time you're a senior citizen, probably over 70.